# If Outlook mail is already sent then do nothing in Worksheet_Change

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a sheet which has an inventory of CDs. If one CD inventory goes under 10 pieces then the sheet triggers mail which is sent automatically.

When I press enter somewhere in the sheet it sends mail repetitively.

```vb
Sub Mail_Radio_Waldrand()
       
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hallo Sari" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Der CD-Bestand von Radio Waldrand ist unter dem Mindestbestand von 10 Stück." & vbNewLine & _
              "Bitte bestellen."
    
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "opr6@dreischiibe.ch"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Marius & die Jagdkapelle: CD-Bestand von Radio Waldrand unterschritten"
        .Body = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        'or use .Send
        .Send
    End With
       
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "opr6@dreischiibe.ch"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Marius & die Jagdkapelle: CD-Bestand von Radio Waldrand unterschritten"
        .Body = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        'or use .Send
        .Send
        
    On Error GoTo 0
           
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I tried `If OutMail = True Then Exit Sub`

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call Materialbestand
End Sub

Sub Materialbestand()
    If Worksheets("2023 Materialbestand").Range("B9") < 20 Then
        Call Mail_Luftpolster_klein
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How is the sub triggered? I believe that code is more needed to figure out where it's going wrong than the sending email sub.

Comment: But your code **is designed to send the mail twice**... Each time after `With OutMail`. The second time it should raise an error, not having an ending `End With`. Try commenting, deleting the second similar group of code lines. Then, which is the purpose of `On Error Resume Next`, except that it does not let you see an error if he case? If it sends it more then twice, please do what is required in the previous comment. How it is the shown sub called?

Comment: Why twice? It sends every time when Even Change happens in the main sheet.
Sub triggers if the inventory is below specific amount. And then Calls this Sub

Comment: If you have `OutMail.Send` two times,  it will send the email twice. And we required to see **the code of the event calling the sub**. Sometimes, the calling code is not good enough. If it is a secret code, I wish you success in solving the problem in your way!

Comment: Sub Materialbestand()

If Worksheets("2023 Materialbestand").Range("B9") < 20 Then
        Call Mail_Luftpolster_klein
    End If


End Sub

Comment: What is that? Shouldn't it be an event (`Change` one)? And please, do  not post code in comments. You may any time edit your question and placed there the relevant piece of information. How can `Materialbestand()` automatically run?

Comment: As soon as a mail has been sent you should set a flag in the sheet to prevent any more mails going out.  If the inventory goes back above 20 then clear the flag.

Answer (score 0):

Focus `WorkSheet_Change` on a single cell.

```vb
Private Sub WorkSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$9" Then
        Call Materialbestand
    End If
End Sub
```